# Add second column for the moth but Find where one month end and adjust to next month

Tags: bash, awk

```
27
27
27
28
28
28
29
29
29
30
30
30
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
```

Column 1 is the day of the month, I want to create a second colum for the month. However my day of month goes over two months. The numbers from 27 to 30 are for month 09  and those from 1 to 3 are for month 10. So the awk script must find where the first month ends and then adjast the month accordingly to the next month

I am truely a starter in wak and trying to learn how to do this in awk. Please forgive me that I cant even come up with a wrong way

Thank you in advance
Patrick

Comment: They always in order ?

Answer (score 0):

This will get abuse for using `getline` but here is a solution

```
awk 'BEGIN{x=1}{getline y < FILENAME}y==1&&!t{x++;t=1}y==2&&t{t=0}{print y,x}' file
```

Gets a line, increments counter on `1` and then unsets a token on `2` so it doesnt continually increment for every `1` just the first in each month.

Didn't actually need getline, was doing it a different way at first.
Here it is without

```
awk 'BEGIN{x=1}$1==1&&!t{x++;t=1}$1==2&&t{t=0}{print $1,x}' file
```

Comment: Jidder, thank you very much for your answer, this does what am looking for. Thank you so so much this is the beging of my lesson in awk

Thanks